# Installing nodejs through Ansible playbook

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, ansible

I have created a Vagrant vm (Ubuntu) and installed Ansible. I can ping my localhost, that means to my vm. I wrote a playbook to install nodejs.

```
---
- hosts: node #it contains localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: install node.js
    shell: apt-get install nodejs
    sudo: yes
```

When I run the playbook the status show success. To my understanding, it should install nodejs and also npm in my vm. However, if I type `node -v`, it shows it is not installed yet.

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant_data$ ansible-playbook ping.yml

PLAY [node] *******************************************************************

TASK: [install node.js] *******************************************************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0

vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant_data$ node -v
The program 'node' can be found in the following packages:
 * node
 * nodejs-legacy
Ask your administrator to install one of them
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong here?

- you are executing a command through `shell` module instead of using a native, idempotent [Ansible module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/apt_module.html);
- you are executing `apt-get` without arguments to prevent interactive prompts ([`-y`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get));
- you are using a long-outdated `sudo` parameter (which in current Ansible version is ignored) instead of [`become`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/become.html);
- finally, you seem to have problems with reading on-screen messages and distinguishing package names: expecting `node.js` to install the `node` executable, while your system clearly states it can be found in `node` or `nodejs-legacy` packages.

---

<sup>Bonus: you are installing - through a separate process - a set of programs which set and utilise user environment variables, but continue to use the shell session without the environment set (this has no direct influence on `node` executable availability, but is a mistake anyway).</sup>